# Thiessen polygons of sub-districts to lie within district boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, voronoi-thiessen

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and am fairly new to it. I have the latitude and longitude of sub-districts, and wish to create Thiessen polygons of these sub-districts. I also have shapefiles for districts (there are about 10 sub-districts within each district), and want the Thiessen polygon of each sub-district to lie completely within it's district, and not spillover to a neighboring district. Thanks!

Comment: Can you indicate how this question is different from the one which is linked as a possible duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

- Select the points for each district. If all the points are in one shapefile you can use [Select by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) to isolate by district. Repeat for each district.
- Use [Create Theissen Polygons](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001m000000) to create your sub-district Theissen polygons (these are also known as Voronoi polygons).

> **Important note from ESRI docs:**
>
> The outside boundary of the output Thiessen polygon feature class is
> the extent of the point input features plus an additional 10%. If the
> Extent environment is set to a specific extent window, this tool tool
> will use the environment setting to set its outside boundary.

The extent draws a square box around the farthest N,S,E,W points in your data. So depending on the size of your district you will probably want to increase this extent value to anywhere from 50% to 300%. All outside borders (extending lines) of your Theissen polygons should come out far enough to touch the district polygon boundaries. You normally click on the **Environments...** button to set this value.

- [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) your sub-district polygons to your district polygons. This will cut off the "long edges" of the Theissen polygons. You should now have a set of Theissen polygons that "fits" each of your districts exactly.
- You can now use [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to bring over attributes from either the district polygons or the points. Do both.
- Use [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) to combine your district/sub district polygons together. Now you have one big sub districts dataset that you can also symbolize based on district because of the attributes from the Spatial Join.

Comment: That was the route I was starting down (Enviroment setting) but got hung up on the rectangular extent bit. I was looking to see if there was a way around that when I found the older question that suggests Clip as you do. Good thorough answer.